# Design of 3 middle dots (...) in qml using Text and Rectangle

Tags: qml

I want to design 3 dots in qml using Text and Rectangle as shown below;

... Hello World ...

But my requirement is 3 dots should lie at the middle of the rectangle and the text (Hello World) as shown in the image. How this can be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I thought first time, 2 approaches came up in my mind:

**1-** Using the middle dot by the help of `html code styles` can achieve this. Here is the [HTML codes](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp) which you can easiy use in `qml`.

Here is the example and output:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id:sample1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 50
        border.color: "black"
        Text {
             id: mytext
             anchors.centerIn: parent
             textFormat: Text.RichText
             text: "&#xB7;" + "&#xB7;" + "&#xB7;" + "   Hello World   " + "&#xB7;" + "&#xB7;" + "&#xB7;"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**2-** You can put the *"Hello world"* text first then you can create another text for dots and put the dots in the mid coordinates beside the main text. This method is not a beautiful approach.

***Note:** When I dig into to other possible solutions, I couldn't see a proper solution to achieve this.*

Comment: Thank you so much. html code styles solved my problem.